# Import terminated unsuccessfully - Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, admin, oracle-xe

I'm trying to import a dump file using imp command in oracle 10g. The following error message is displayed. Kindly assist

```
C:\Documents and Settings>imp 'rdata/rdata@nxtgen' file="D:\oracle\schema.dmp" 
log=D:\oracle\schema.log full=y

Import: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Fri Jun 21 11:54:29 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


IMP-00058:
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully

C:\Documents and Settings>
```

Comment: Does `the D:\oracle` directory exist, and is it writable? Was a log file created - if so please add the contents to the question.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes the directory exists and log file was created with the error message as "IMP-00058: 
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully"

Comment: Yes? There isn't much to go on. I don't use `imp` in Windows (or at all, since `impdp` is the norm from 10g), but might it be unhappy with the quotes around the credentials - does `imp rdata/rdata@nxtgen ...` make any difference? Otherwise I have no idea I'm afraid.